# Cant switch the java version used by spring plugin

Tags: spring, eclipse

I know that there are similar topics upon this issue but none of them helped me to solve the errors... 
I am on a Spring 2.5 project using:

```
1) Maven 3.3.9:
   Apache Maven 3.3.9
   Maven home: /usr/share/maven
   Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
   Default locale: es_AR, platform encoding: UTF-8
   OS name: "linux", version: "4.8.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And while running mvn jetty:run I got the following issue:

```
[ERROR] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher:
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher

I even change the compiler plugin and set it to java 1.6 as this spring version doesnt work with java 8 and things dont work... Does anyone have a clue ?... I am on Eclipse and also change the compliance level and nothing... no success

Comment: applicationContext.xml is not a jetty feature, dropping embedded-jetty tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable is the problem.

It should contain `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`
instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`

Also, I'm guessing your `$PATH` contains another, older java version.
You can test that by executing `java --version` on the command line.